# Remove backslashes from response entity Json in Java

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am testing my Rest controller and when i print the results in java they seem to be okay but on swagger or postman it return slashes. How do i remove these.

In Java i print the object with a log and the result is as below:

ReturnObject

```
    {
      create=Create{
        create={
          "Apartment": "Flat",
          "Drink": {
            "Alchol": {
              "Beer": {
                "Dutch": "Groeshe",
                "Zimbo": "Zambezi"
              },
              "Wine": "pocupine"
            },
            "NonAlcoholic": {
              "fizzy": "Coke",
              "juice": "liquifruit"
            }
          },
          "fruit": "Apple",
          "size": "Large",
          "color": "Red",
          "Proffesion": [
            "Java",
            "Lawyer"
          ],
          "cars": {
            "type": "BMW",
            "Color": "Brown"
          }
        }
      },
      update=null,
      delete=null
    }
```

I googled and nothing in java seems to solve this problem. Please assist

```
    @RestController
    public class ProcessController<T extends Serializable> {

    
    @Autowired
    private EngineImpl engine;

    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/processEngine", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<ReturnObject<T>> processEngine(@RequestBody final Request request) throws Exception {
             
        ReturnObject<T> response = engine.calculate((T) request.getA(), (T) request.getB());

        LOG.info("ReturnObject engine response parameters: " + response);
        //Prints: ReturnObject{create=Create{create={"Apartment":"Flat","Drink":{"Alchol":{"Beer":{"Dutch":"Groeshe","Zimbo":"Zambezi"},"Wine":"pocupine"},"NonAlcoholic":{"fizzy":"Coke","juice":"liquifruit"}},"fruit":"Apple","size":"Large","color":"Red","Proffesion":["Java","Lawyer"],"cars":{"type":"BMW","Color":"Brown"}}}, update=null, delete=null}
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Expected:

```
    {
      "create": {
        "create": {
            "Apartment": "Flat",
            "Drink": {
                "Alchol": {
                    "Beer": {
                        "Dutch": "Groeshe",
                        "Zimbo": "Zambezi"

                    },
                    "Wine": "pocupine"

                },
                "NonAlcoholic": {
                    "fizzy": "Coke",
                    "juice": "liquifruit"
                }
            },
            "fruit": "Apple",
            "size": "Large",
            "color": "Red",
            "Proffesion": ["Java", "Lawyer"],
            "cars": {
                "type": "BMW",
                "Color": "Brown"
            }
        },
        "update": null,
        "delete": null
    }
}
```

Actual:

```
    {
      "create": {
        "create": "{\"Apartment\":\"Flat\",\"Drink\":{\"Alchol\":{\"Beer\":{\"Dutch\":\"Groeshe\",\"Zimbo\":\"Zambezi\"},\"Wine\":\"pocupine\"},\"NonAlcoholic\":{\"fizzy\":\"Coke\",\"juice\":\"liquifruit\"}},\"fruit\":\"Apple\",\"size\":\"Large\",\"color\":\"Red\",\"Proffesion\":[\"Java\",\"Lawyer\"],\"cars\":{\"type\":\"BMW\",\"Color\":\"Brown\"}}"
      },
      "update": null,
      "delete": null
    }
```

Comment: remove the .toString() method from your object if you "override" the toString() method in you response class. your Jackson or gson lib will automatically take the responsibility of parsing the objects.

Comment: @SivarajVelayutham i tried removing the toString() method from response object but there is no change.I also removed from the dependant classes still no change

Comment: if your ReturnObject<T> response = engine.calculate((T) request.getA(), (T) request.getB());  return sting then change controller return type ResponseEntity<String>

Comment: Try removing <T extends Serializable> from controller as I think it will make the rest response to string.If it works let us know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the parser, to get pretty JSON string, guess you're using Jackson,  so you can do it in this way:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(yourObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

After Second "create" it is Basically converting your value to String.
please implement this annotation
    @PostMapping("/api/processEngine")
please Try this and Let Me know immediately